# Going to a certain tab in tabbarcontroller when receiving push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have the following `storyboard`
[image]

What I want now is that when I got a `push notification` I should go to a certain tab inside my `tabbarController`.

I now was wondering what the best practice was for making this happen?
I could set the `self.window.rootController` to the correct `ViewController` but then I have a problem when the user presses logout. When he presses logout he should be redirected to the very first ViewController. The one you see at the most left.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {


       if (self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil)
            {
            [self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

                {
                    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                    tabbarcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tabbar"];
                    [tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:1];
                    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tabbarcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];

                }
                UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                tabbarcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tabbar"];
                  [tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:1];
                [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tabbarcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

                UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                tabbarcontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tabbar"];
                [tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:1];
                [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tabbarcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Comment: it will always switch your root controller to tabbarcontoller first viewcontroller , even when you device will receive a notification while running.

Comment: [tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:3];(change the number according to the tabbar )